# Mongoose: Trying to do a forEach in the array of items in a collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to use the `.find` function in **mongoose** to get the entire amount of items in my collection. Then I tried using a `forEach` loop to set a variable using the information to push into an array.

For some reason it won't work, I tried console logging any errors but it wasn't returning anything, am I using this function correctly?

```
[ { _id: 5b7e933aa5b5e7165fd02e77,
id: 7151,
location: 'X: 151.1869; Y: -1006.755; Z: -98.99999',
price: 5000,
door: 'X: -2.0055665969848633; Y: 20.169893264770508; Z: 71.10984802246094',
__v: 0 },


{ _id: 5b7e96042ba33b18dd03740f,
    id: 6264,
    location: 'X: 151.1869; Y: -1006.755; Z: -98.99999',
    price: 5000,
    door: 'X: -405.9184265136719; Y: 1160.5306396484375; Z: 325.9139404296875',
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5b7e9664344f8c198f0fd266,
    id: 1694,
    location: 'X: 151.1869; Y: -1006.755; Z: -98.99999',
    price: 5000,
    door: 'X: -406.7716369628906; Y: 1162.4755859375; Z: 325.9158630371094',
    __v: 0 } ]

    House.find({}, function(err, house) {
        console.log(house);
        if(err) console.log(err);
        house.forEach(function(h) {
            let loadHouse = {
                id: h.id,
                location: JSON.parse(h.location),
                price: h.price,
                door: JSON.parse(h.door),
            }
    houses.push(loadHouse);
    console.log(houses);
});
```

Comment: Please post the result of ` console.log(house);` in question

Comment: Added it above the code

Comment: You are also missing the closing bracket of `forEach()` in your question

Comment: What do you get in `console.log(houses);`?

Comment: Is `houses` declared?

Comment: Oh, nothing showed up in the console for houses, and yes it's declared

Comment: The errors seem to be within the forEach, you are trying to use JSON.parse on non-valid json strings. (`JSON.parse('X: -405.9184265136719; Y: 1160.5306396484375; Z: 325.9139404296875')`)

Comment: Oh okay that fixed it thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors seem to be within the forEach, you are trying to use `JSON.parse()` with non-valid json strings.

```
JSON.parse('X: -405.9184265136719; Y: 1160.5306396484375; Z: 325.9139404296875')
```

So for now you should remove the `JSON.parse()`

(Sorry I posted that in comment but should have done it as an answer)